# Adding a status bar to c++ console applications

Tags: c++, linux, console, progress-bar, status

I am making a linux application using C++ and it will print info out to the console.  Parts of the program will take a while to compute and I would like to add a status bar in the console similar to the one used in wget (I put my own depiction below).

```
%complete[===========>               ] eta
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this goal?  Are there any useful libraries that make it easy to add this functionality?

Comment: What kind of console are you using? Some have native support for moving to a status line and back from a status line. Check the `tsl` and `fsl` capabilities in the terminfo or termcap database.

Comment: I posted an answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956442/displaying-completed-while-executing-in-c/4958152#4958152) (_"displaying % completed while executing in C"_) which mainly deals with controlling the terminal cursor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your program is like wget, that is, it's basically a batch program without the need for a full-screen UI (for which I would recommend [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)), you can use the trick to print a carriage return (but not line feed) after your line; the next thing you write will overwrite the same line.

Here's a demonstration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                std::cout << "Status: " << i << "\r" << std::flush;
                sleep(1);
        }
        std::cout << "Completed.\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice trick. But be careful that each line is as long as the preceding one (otherwise, output ending spaces)

Answer (score 1):

The [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) library should be useful to you. Or you can write the progress line char by char, using backspaces, calling `fflush` or `std::flush`, etc.

A simpler way would just to output dots...

Answer (score 0):

You can use debconf-apt-progress to run a command while displaying a progress line like apt does. Your command needs to report progress over a pipe fd back to debconf-apt-progress. I haven't figured out how to extract this functionality out of debconf-apt-progress yet.